# How to convert string type array into array in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, string

My string is: `"[\"0\", \"0\", \"1\", \"0\", \"0\", \"0\", \"0\"]"`

I want solution like array: `["1","1","1","1","1","1","1"]`

**Solution1:**

```
let test = "[\"0\", \"0\", \"1\", \"0\", \"0\", \"0\", \"0\"]"
let array = test.map( { String($0) })
debugPrint(array ?? []) //No use
```

**Solution2:**

```
var unescaped: String {
    let entities = ["\0": "\\0",
                    "\t": "\\t",
                    "\n": "\\n",
                    "\r": "\\r",
                    "\"": "\\\"",
                    "\'": "\\'",
                    "": "\"",
    ]
    
    return entities
        .reduce(self) { (string, entity) in
            string.replacingOccurrences(of: entity.value, with: entity.key)
        }
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "\\\\(?!\\\\)", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "\\\\", with: "\\")
}


debugPrint("[\"0\", \"0\", \"1\", \"0\", \"0\", \"0\", \"0\"]".unescaped) //No use
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string is JSON. An easy way is

```
let test = "[\"0\", \"0\", \"1\", \"0\", \"0\", \"0\", \"0\"]"
let array = try! JSONDecoder().decode([String].self, from: Data(test.utf8))
```